# Production database so much slower than development database?

Tags: performance, mariadb

I am running a script on both servers, one in my docker local developement system, and one on production. However, the same script is running much slower on production than on development. I am using MariaDB 10.5 on both. My developement system has 12 GB RAM while my production is 32 GB RAM. They both are SSD hard drive. I temporary turned off nginx and ran the test at midnight where there were basically no request being made. It's also the exact same database. I also ran these queries directly on MySQL console and still the speed was much slower. Also, there are no triggers on development and production.

This is in my development:

```
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, ' ', '') ;  270.34
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = TRIM(postal_code) ;  292.88
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '       ', ' '); ;  263.64
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '
', ' '); ;  265.08
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = REGEXP_REPLACE(postal_code, '[[:space:]]+', ' '); ;  332.59
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '+', ' ') ;  266.14
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '*', '') ;  275.96
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '%', '') ;  267.72
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '$', '') ;  263.29
 UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '#', '') ;  265.83
```

This is in my production:

```
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, ' ', '') ;  2188.6
UPDATE location SET postal_code = TRIM(postal_code) ;  2082.06
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '       ', ' '); ;  2073.88
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '
', ' '); ;  2042.94
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REGEXP_REPLACE(postal_code, '[[:space:]]+', ' '); ;  2086.55
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '+', ' ') ;  2004
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '*', '') ;  1997.51
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '%', '') ;  2076.03
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '$', '') ;  2078.69
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, '#', '') ;  2033.26
```

I'm not asking for someone to solve this but how can I investigate this? What can be the possible culprits?

`htop` on development while running the script
[image]

`htop` on production while running the script
[image]

`iotop` had similar results.

@Vérace
This is output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE location;` in production and development:

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `province` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ONTARIO',
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'CANADA',
  `latitude` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `house_size` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `house_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ac_exists_boolean` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `previous_ac_age` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `furnace_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `previous_furnace_age` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `previous_furnace_efficiency` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `electrical_panel_full` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_fuel_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_fuel_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gas_conversion` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `geo_pin` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `geo_pin_valid_boolean` enum('Y','N') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `gas_meter_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `nosi` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `location_id` (`location_id`),
  KEY `location_street_number_idx` (`street_number`),
  KEY `location_street_name_idx` (`street_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=844557 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

@mustaccio
This is output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. The production database is on the left side.
https://www.diffchecker.com/yMBZnEQV

@Vérace,
I've added a diff of the `my.cnf` variables. The left one is the production one, right one development.
https://www.diffchecker.com/PtgE7sHH

This is the output of `mysqltuner.pl` on production.

```
MySQLTuner 1.8.1 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.5.12-MariaDB-1:10.5.12+maria~focal
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Log file  doesn't exist
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 15.5G (Tables: 1668)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 897.5K (Tables: 59)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 22h 15m 0s (13M q [80.031 qps], 621K conn, TX: 94G, RX: 1G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 98% / 2%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 31.4G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 19.4G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 16.5G global + 19.5M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 19.4G (61.90% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 19.4G (61.84% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (151/13M)
[!!] Highest connection usage: 100%  (152/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.07%  (414/621325)
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (163 temp sorts / 312K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 1054
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 77% (262K on disk / 338K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (353 created / 621K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 99% (22M hits / 22M requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache(3000) is upper than number of tables(2085)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (162/32K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (5K immediate / 5K locks)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.
 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 4 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.5.12-MariaDB-1:10.5.12+maria~focal)
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (24M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/59.0K
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 16.0G/15.5G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 4.0G * 1/16.0G should be equal to 25%
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 128 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (12593475773 hits/ 12593738654 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 246.44% (77137 hits/ 31300 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 108437 writes)
 
-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/328.0K
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 97.5% (10M cached / 255K reads)
 
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
 
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
 
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
 
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: OFF
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: OFF
[--] This is a standalone server
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Variables to adjust:
    max_connections (> 151)
    wait_timeout (< 28800)
    interactive_timeout (< 28800)
    join_buffer_size (> 1.0M, or always use indexes with JOINs)
```

**Edit:**

I also took the same exact `my.cnf` from development and took it in production. It was still slow. So I don't think that it's any of the mariadb variables. I also ran the command `mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --optimize --all-databases` but no success.

**Edit 2:**
output of `ulimit -a` in production left, development right
https://www.diffchecker.com/OJWhXxwi

**Edit 3**
Output of `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "location"` on development

```
MariaDB [phs]> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "location";
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| Name     | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | Max_index_length | Temporary |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| location | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 227116 |             99 |    22593536 |               0 |     43122688 |  29360128 |         844557 | 2021-08-29 16:01:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N         |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Output of `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "location"` on production

```
MariaDB [phs_p]> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "location";
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| Name     | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | Max_index_length | Temporary |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| location | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 227281 |            113 |    25739264 |               0 |     39976960 |   6291456 |         844563 | 2021-08-31 00:37:00 | 2021-08-31 14:03:42 | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N         |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

**Edit 4**
These are the results after 24 hours uptime of the production server. I also updated the link for `my.cnf` above, so it's working now.

I've attached the output of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` - left production, right development.

https://www.diffchecker.com/StIjIm0y

I've attached the output of `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES` - left production, right development.

https://www.diffchecker.com/N8LPoIs4

I've attached the output of `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` - left production, right development.

https://www.diffchecker.com/z2MmFLGO

I've attached the output of `STATUS` - left production, right development.

https://www.diffchecker.com/sQ5TmUCY

I've attached the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` - left production, right development.

https://www.diffchecker.com/9Vuzgkaj

I also did `ANALYZE TABLE location` and it was fine. I did notice MySQL server went away though. It did once also in one of the commands above.

```
MariaDB [phs_p]> ANALYZE TABLE location;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    481218
Current database: phs_p

+----------------+---------+----------+----------+
| Table          | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+----------------+---------+----------+----------+
| phs_p.location | analyze | status   | OK       |
+----------------+---------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.082 sec)
```

Comment: Discussion on this question has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129089/discussion-on-question-by-raza-production-database-so-much-slower-than-developme).

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the [original mysqltuner output](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/298723/7), configuration of this instance allowed the DB to use 177Gb of the physical 32.  This is not optimal for performance. [Hiding this information](https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/298723/9) is not optimal in solving a performance problem.

If this turns out to be an IO problem (CPU could indicate filesystem), I would review the update script to only update those records where something needs cnanging, eg.:

```
UPDATE location SET postal_code = REPLACE(postal_code, ' ', '')
  where postal_code like '% %';
```

Currently, each of your updates updates the entire table, perhaps for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your 10.5.12 Prod server [mysqld] section

```
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay=10000  # from 0 when busy, give the CPU a quick break
innodb_concurrency_tickets=10000  # from 0 to minimize reque's
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 35,512
analyze_sample_percentage=0  # from 100 to limit sampling time expended-autocalc
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=ON  # from OFF to minimize deadlocks
```

There are many more opportunities to improve your configuration.

Your production server has 4 CPU's and the development server has 16 CPU's. This may be contributing to slow prod.

Observations, MariaDB 10.5.12 went General Availability on 8/6/2021, barely a month ago.  You may be finding something that was missed in this release and if you have time, open a trouble ticket with MySQL developers.  This usually can be avoided in the future, if you will avoid release updates until they have had 90 days on the street to allow someone else the pleasure of finding trouble, reporting it, waiting on corrective release.

Your com_begin and com_commit counts are different by 208 in 3 days.  This would point to someone forgetting to 'commit' data before the process ends which releases resources used.

Normally we see com_savepoint matched with com_release_savepoint.  It looks like 36,880 were not released in 3 days, resulting in resources not freed when done with the process.